# How do dota 2 bots pick their heroes?

Tags: dota-2

Since the game is in beta phase and I'm a total noob at the game I find it natural to play with bots. My bot match consists of 3 hard bots on my team and 4 easy bots on the opposite team, plus me of course.

Well, with this setting the bots always seem to pick the same heroes every time. In every game I have a bane, a Kunkka, a Sven and always a vengeful spirit. I have been playing the game for 2 weeks and **not once** have I seen the bots pick a hero such as beastmaster, wisp or clockwork, they always select the same heroes. I'd like to practice with other heroes than these and learn how to work with other heroes except Sven.

How do bots in dota 2 pick their heroes? Why don't they pick other heroes besides the ones mentioned?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason bots only select a limited set of heroes is because the AI hasn't been scripted for every hero in the game yet. Assuming you pick before them, the bots will then try to counterpick any heroes you or your allies have.

You can also 'suggest' heroes which will cause allied bots to choose those heroes, if AI exists for them.

As far as I can tell, the only AI scripted heroes currently are:

- Axe
- Bane
- Bloodseeker
- Bounty Hunter
- Bristleback
- Chaos Knight
- Crystal Maiden
- Dazzle
- Death Prophet
- Dragon Knight
- Drow
- Earthshaker
- Jakiro
- Juggernaut
- Kunkka
- Lich
- Lina
- Lion
- Luna
- Necrophos
- Omniknight
- Oracle
- Pudge
- Razor
- Riki
- Sand King
- Shadow Fiend
- Skywrath Mage
- Sniper
- Sven
- Tidehunter
- Tiny
- Vengeful Spirit
- Viper
- Warlock
- Windranger
- Witch Doctor
- Wraith King
- Zeus

Valve periodically adds new bots in their weekly updates, but as of late they have been focusing primarily on AI enhancements instead of adding more heroes.

Comment: That is a possibility, if they have to code each bot in particular it's going to be a while before every hero can be played by bots :(

Comment: @ThePlan If you think about it, each hero makes use of varying item builds, have different roles, and use their skills differently. Since that's the case, it's not as simple as creating a generic AI that can just pick any hero in the pool (at least if you want an AI that will do a little more than last hit/deny, push with their team, defend towers, etc.).

Comment: Yeah that's true. Thanks for your answer and sorry I couldn't accept it, for some reason I had a timer on.

Comment: @ThePlan not the say league of legends and dota 2 are similar beyond concept ... but Riot has taken about 2 years to start doing serious work on AI *after beta*, and even then the performance is poor and only certain champions can be played. Valve probably has roughly the same size of team dedicated to this, although dota definitely has far more skilled bots in the works than league, so given that dota 2 is only in beta you could be looking at more than a year before AI can play every hero at a reasonable skill level, depending on Valve's plans for release. So don't hold your breath just yet.

Comment: @SadlyNot There's actually only one person doing bot development at Valve as far as we've heard: ChrisC

Comment: @Decency Then he's done a pretty good job thus far. I haven't paid attention a lot but are bots able to use all active abilities on items?

Comment: If you check the patch notes, you can see that a couple of heroes have been added in a patch http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=69544

Comment: Fyi, you can't suggest heroes anymore; that's no longer part of the hero selection screen.